# Difference between list() and [:]

Tags: python, list, syntax

If we have a list `s`, is there any difference between calling `list(s)` versus `s[:]`? It seems to me like they both create new list objects with the exact elements of `s`.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, they *should* create a (shallow) copy of the list.

Note that there is one corner case (which is hardly worth mentioning) where it might be different...

```
list = tuple  # Don't ever do this!
list_copy = list(some_list)  # Oops, actually it's a tuple ...
actually_list_copy = some_list[:]
```

With that said, **nobody in their right mind should ever shadow the builtin** `list` **like that.**

My advice, use whichever you feel is easier to read and works nicely in the current context.

- `list(...)` makes it explicit that the output is a list and will make a list out of *any* iterable.
- `something[:]` is a common idiom for "give me a shallow copy of this sequence, I don't really care what kind of sequence it is ...", but it doesn't work on arbitrary iterables.

Comment: Not that it is super important, but `[:]` generally outperforms `list()`.  Running a simple `timeit` test with the list `[1, 2, 3]` yields `0.9552267117748205` for `list()` and `0.4996651809098642` for `[:]`.  But like I said, this is somewhat nitpicking; the time difference is negligible in most cases.

Comment: @iCodez -- That's true, I've come across it before.  The reasoning is that `list(...)` requires a global lookup which is somewhat expensive.  And the global lookup is required because of the crazy case where a user shadows `list`.  With slicing, the method lookup is done once (during bytecode generation) and is simply invoked on the object.  There might be other reasons as well. . . the implementation could probably optimize `list.__getitem__` as it can know the memory locations of the objects in the output easily, but `list` might resort to calling `.next()` a bunch of times...

Answer (score 1):

list() is better - it's more readable. Other than that there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is use `list()`. In google type `python [:]` then type `python list`.

If s is a list then there is no difference, but will s always be a list? Or could it be a sequence or a generator?

```
In [1]: nums = 1, 2, 3

In [2]: nums
Out[2]: (1, 2, 3)

In [3]: nums[:]
Out[3]: (1, 2, 3)

In [4]: list(nums)
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]

In [7]: strings = (str(x) for x in nums)

In [8]: strings
Out[8]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f77be460550>

In [9]: strings[:]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-358af12435ff> in <module>()
----> 1 strings[:]

TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

In [10]: list(strings)
Out[10]: ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize, but as ventsyv mentioned, `s[:]` and `list(s)` both create a copy of `s`.
Note you can check if an object is the same using `is` and `id()` can be used to get the object's memory address to actually see if they are the same or not.

```
>>> s = [1,2,3]
>>> listed_s = list(s)
>>> id(s)
44056328
>>> id(listed_s) # different
44101840
>>> listed_s is s
False
>>> bracket_s = s[:]
>>> bracket_s is s
False
>>> id(bracket_s)
44123760
>>> z = s # points to the same object in memory
>>> z is s
True
>>> id(z)
44056328
>>>
```

> id(...)
>       id(object) -> integer
>
> ```
> Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
> simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)
> ```